# How to count duplicate elements in a vector using R

Tags: r, vector, count, find-occurrences

I need to write a function that receives 2 arguments in R:
first a number = X
second a vector = V
I need that this function would return the max number of the identical straight occurrences of X 
for example:
f(6, c(7,6,6,3,7,9,3,6,6,6,8,9)
should return 3

Comment: `max(rle(your.vector)$lengths)`  should suffice.

Comment: I think this would ignore the x which I need to choose for "running" on the vector

Comment: Sorry- I skimmed the question and thought you just wanted the max length regardless of value.  The answers provided include the ability to report for each value in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may not need a function

```
dat <- c(7,6,6,3,7,9,3,6,6,6,8,9)

fmax <- function(x, vec){
  v <- rle(vec)
  max(v$lengths[v$values == x])
}
fmax(x=6, vec=dat)
[1] 3
```

when x in absent from dat

```
fmax <- function(x, vec){
  if(x %in% vec){
    v <- rle(vec)
    max(v$lengths[v$values == x])
  } else 0
}
fmax(x=20, vec=dat)
[1] 0
```

Comment: thanks!however, the issue is that I need a general function that would do so, and not specifically with the digit 6 or any specific vector.

Comment: this is a general function. change dat and x accordingly to get the desired output. Am I wrong?

Comment: and if the X is not part of the vector, how will force it to return "0"

Comment: This is an extension to your textual question.

Comment: should I re-write my question?

Comment: See if the answer is enough for your case but yes. In any case you should provide as much information as possible to enhance the change to receive better answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
r <- numeric()
j <- 0
X <- 6
for(i in 1:length(V){
j <- ifelse(v[i]==X,j+1,0)
r[i] <- j
}

max(r)
```

if you wanna have the maximal length for all elements in the vector:

```
a <- c(7,6,6,3,7,9,3,6,6,6,8,9)
b <- rle(a)
b <- data.frame(length=b$lengths, values=b$values)
aggregate(b, by=list(b$values), FUN=max)
```

Comment: thanks!however, the issue is that I need a general function that would do so, and not specifically with the digit 6 or any specific vector.